# Function with some partition such that $\underline{S}(f,P) = \overline{S}(f,P)$ implies that $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus, integration, partitions-for-integration

This posts begins with a question for a homework I had, and that question is rather simple:

If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function and there exists some partition of $[0,1]$ such that $\underline{S}(f,P) = \overline{S}(f,P)$, then $f$ is constant.

I thought that if we define $f$ like this:
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 
      0 & 0 \leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      1 & \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1 
   \end{cases}
$$
And take the partition $P = \{0, \frac{1}{2},1\}$ then we have our counter example, however someone else pointed out that with this partition $\underline{S}(f,P) \neq \overline{S}(f,P)$, because $inf\{f(x)|x \in  [\frac{1}{2}, 1]\}= 0 \neq 1 = sup\{f(x)|x \in  [\frac{1}{2}, 1]\}$

This person also said that the proposition is true, because if such partition exists then for every subinterval induced by this partition P we would have that $inf\{f(x)|x \in [x_{i -1}, x_i]\}= sup\{f(x)|x \in  [x_{i -1}, x_i]\}$, and that would imply that the function is indeed, constant.

So, is that reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is correct. Did you have some specific doubts about it?

Comment: Nope, other than I was a bit skeptical about it at first, because the result is true when the equality happens for all partitions, but the fact that you only need one for it to be true is something that I found striking, thanks for your reply!

Comment: No worries. Note that your counterexample does work when using strict (set) partitions into intervals (where you don't have to worry about the subintervals intersecting on endpoints).